# "More than one element found for locator" warning

Tags: angularjs, testing, warnings, protractor, end-to-end

In one of my tests, I'm locating an element using a `CSS selector`:

```
element(by.css("ul.nav button"))
```

There is more than one element matching the query, but, since I need only the first one, I'm okay with the selector.

The problem is, `protractor` throws a warning:

> WARNING - more than one element found for locator
>   By.cssSelector("ul.nav button") - the first result will be used

Is it possible to suppress the warning? In other words, how can I let `protractor` know that I'm aware of the problem and don't want the warning to be shown anymore?

---

Using `protractor` development version (installed directly from the master branch).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
element.all(by.css("ul.nav button")).first()
```

Basically, this tells Protractor that you already know there's more than one element, and you just want the first one (like you said in your question).

Comment: That works! As a bonus and out of curiosity, though, would be useful to know if it is possible to silence the warning, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If there was one, it would be [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js). I don't see anything like that, though, and I think the reason is because non-specific locators make for very fragile tests.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid I can turn it off only by setting an appropriate `logLevel` which would by extension turn off other warnings which is not good. But I totally agree about your last point, makes sense to me. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: You've answered a couple of my questions, so I'm glad I could return the favor.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is there for a reason. You've tied your tests too closely to your data. The selector is too general & you should be more specific. Either by saying `element(by.css("ul.nav button:nth-child(1)"))` or scoping your search differently. Protractor tests aren't supposed to be testing style or dom, they're supposed to be testing business logic.

Comment: After long consideration, I'm downvoting this answer because: 1) it makes an accusation against the OP that, given the simplicity of the question, is completely unwarranted; 2) the given solution, although it may work, depends on a presumed DOM structure which is not stated in the question; 3) the answer claims that the given solution has specific advantages over the OP's code, but in reality it does not have these advantages; and 4) outside of the code sample, the answer amounts to little more than non-sequiturs and sermonizing.

Answer (score 4):

Less code:

```
$$("ul.nav button").first()
```

Comment: This is great!!

Answer (score 2):

Do not underestimate xpath. You can solve thousands of problems with it, including this one

```
let elem = element(by.xpath('(//div//a)[3]'))
```

You can specify the number of element to use. Keep in mind the numbers start from 1, not 0 as usually in js