# How to chain `element` and `element.all`?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

The problem is very similar to this one ["More than one element found for locator" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464604/more-than-one-element-found-for-locator-warning): I have `ng-repeat`, inside it I have two `div`s, with `ng-if` on them, so only one `div` is shown. Every `div` in `ng-repeat` has equal class `login__cell-link`.

I need to check value in this `div`s, so I choose the block with them using

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in array')).then( allElements => {
  allElements[i].element(by.className('login__cell-link')).getText();
});
```

The problem is warning:

> WARNING - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .login__cell-link) - the first result will be used

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464809/4753661 says to use: `element.all(by.css("ul.nav button")).first()`

But I get error:

> [TypeError: allElements[i].element.all is not a function]

How can I chain `element` and `element.all`, or are there better solutions to check one `div` in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `.all()` not `.element.all()` when chaining:

```
allElements[i].all(by.className('login__cell-link')).first().getText();
```

By the way, you don't need to resolve the promise explicitly here and can chain it all the way:

```
element
  .all(by.repeater('item in array'))
  .get(i)
  .all(by.className('login__cell-link'))
  .first()
  .getText();
```

Shameless self-promotion: if you want to catch this kind of errors early, you can use `ESLint` static code analysis tool together with `eslint-plugin-protractor`'s [`correct-chaining` rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/correct-chaining.md).

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. On the last part - in my code I have a wrapper function and an iterator, to check `allElements.length` divs, that's just smaller version of the code, that's why I resolve the promise this way. Once again thanks a lot for your help!