# Instead of xpath what i can select from my code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

For the mentioned code

```
<div class="md-input-infix">
  <!--template bindings={}-->
  <input class="md-input-element ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="md-input-19-input" spellcheck="false" type="text">
    <!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}-->
    <label class="md-input-placeholder md-empty md-float" for="md-input-19-input">First name * 
    <!--template bindings={}-->
  </label>
</div>
```

1.)In this code, id changes every time.So,I will not be able to select id as locator

2.)I can use CSS by type="text",but on the page there is many more elements with this type ="text".So, this will also not work.

3)I am working on chrome for inspecting element.In this case, if I could select XPath, it will be coming with id inside it.

4)I don't want to go with the absolute XPath.

6)Someone can provide me the solution for this problem.

Comment: use xpath: `//label[text()='First Name']//preceding-sibling::input` or you can try other approach as get Id using the for attribute of label. And use that id.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what would you like to do with the Selection? Click or Double-Click or getText() ?

Comment: I want to pass the values in the text field, for that, I want the locator but don't want to go with the Xpath.

Comment: when i am doing this with id it is showing me the error as NoElement one.

Comment: So ,what should i use now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var elmDiv = element.all(by.cssContainingText('div', 'First name')).last();
var elmInput = elmDiv.element(by.css('[id^="md"]'))
```

Comment: ,hey thanks a lot ,it is working very well with all my fields.So, I just want to know the logic behind this .Using elmInput.click(),I am able to click on the elements and now it is not showing me the error as "More than one element exist with this locator". Can u pls tell me the logic as how u r using last .Because as per my knowledge is concerned about last ,it is going to retrieve last element.

Comment: hi @AnjaliSingh , what happens is we tried to get all `div` that contains the text `First name` and based from your html, the last `div` contains the `input` element. Since we now know that the `input` element is inside the `div`. We are able to locate it easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CSS selector?

```
 input[class="md-input-element ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"]
```

Or you could try locating the parent element first with:

```
div[class="md-input-infix"]
```

And then search within its descendants.

Try and see if this helps:

```
element.all(by.css('input[class="md-input-element ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"]')).each(function(element) {
  element.sendKeys('blah blah');
});
```

Comment: Tried these both ways. I can use this way for the first field that is " first name",but there is the same class for last name field too. So, It will show me the error saying more than one element found.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28464809/5787172 . Or you could loop through all the elements if you need each one.

Comment: Then for the second field what I will do.

Comment: @AnjaliSingh have you tried using the code i added in the edit?

Comment: Hey, this will work only for the first field but not for the other fields.I have mentioned in my query that there are many elements in the page with this class name .

Comment: It's a loop, it's supposed to work for every element with this specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
var el = element(by.css("label:contains('Low Touch Client Name')"));
var elementID = el.getAttribute('id');    
var inputBox = element(by.id(elementID));
inputBox .sendKeys('my text');
```

Comment: Showing me the error as  Failed: input must be a string

Comment: `getAttribute` returns a promise.  The above code will not work the way it is written